# mvc4 apply default text to text entry box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I think I once read about some kind of model attribute that can be set so that default text is displayed within a textbox wheh the @Html.EditorFor is used in the view.

I've tried the following but no joy:

**In the model**

```
[Display(Name="Your Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Your Name")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
```

In the view

> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewTestimonial.AuthorName)

Does such an attribute exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Matt's answer didn't work for me. I had to change from @Html.EditorFor to @Html.TextBoxFor then it worked ok, so the line in my view is:

```
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewTestimonial.AuthorName, new { placeholder = "Your Name" })</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding place holder

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewTestimonial.AuthorName, new { placeholder = "Your Name" })
```

More info here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp